# NSURL doesn´t find video file in mainBundle

Tags: sprite-kit, nsurl

i´d like to play a video file in a skvideonode but every time i try to build my scene i get this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

my code looks like this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"m4v"]];

SKVideoNode *intro = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithVideoURL:fileURL];


intro.size = CGSizeMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);          
intro.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
[self addChild:intro];
[intro play];
```

i´ve tried different ways but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does an "intro.m4v" exist in the root folder of the bundle? In Xcode that files must not be in a *folder reference* indicated by a blue instead of a yellow group (folder) icon. Secondly, note that case is important, ie if the file's name is actually "Intro.m4v" it can't be found on a device if you look for "intro.m4v".

Comment: Has your file been added to your target and bundle?

Comment: it exists in root folder and main bundle. i tried also every possible file name with and without suffix

Answer (score 0):

it is in mainBundle and my code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"m4v"]];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

SKVideoNode *intro = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:player];
    intro.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height);
    intro.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    intro.zPosition = 1;
    [self addChild:intro];
```

the videoNode shows a black screen.